# Looking for a macro to open a .csv file in a specific sheet in an open workbook

Tags: excel, vba

My aim is to have a button that runs a macro to firstly choose the .csv I want to import then copy the .csv in to a specific sheet on the workbook, is this possible?  The button will be on a worksheet called 'CONVERSION' and the .csv should be copied to 'IMPORT'.  I've tried several posts on the forum without an success so far.

This is as far as I have got without errors

```
Sub load_csv() 
Dim fStr As String 
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) .Show 
   If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then 
     MsgBox "Cancel Selected" 
     Exit Sub 
   End If 'fStr is the file path and name of the file you selected. 
  fStr = .SelectedItems(1) 
  End With 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub load_csv()

    Dim fStr As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Cancel Selected"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'fStr is the file path and name of the file you selected.
        fStr = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IMPORT").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fStr, Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will open your csv and allow a copy/paste accordingly.

```
x = ActiveWorkbook.Name
y = Application.GetOpenFilename 'Opens dialog box and sets y to selected file
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= y, Origin:=65001, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2,1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True 'more arrays for more columns if you have them...  this code is for the text import wizard.
y = ActiveWorkbook.Name 'renames the file to the open file

Workbooks(y).ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Copy 'use a different sheet and range depending on what you are trying to copy.
Workbooks(x).ActiveSheet(Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'use a different sheet or range depending on paste area
```